# cassandra how would the query look like?

Tags: cassandra

I have seen this data model:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS social_media.posts_by_user (
user_id uuid,
post_id uuid,
message_text text,
created_on timestamp,
deleted boolean,
user_full_name text,
PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, created_on))
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS social_media.user_timeline (
follower_id uuid,
post_id uuid,
user_id uuid,
location_name text,
user_full_name text,
created_on timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, created_on))
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS social_media.post_counts (
likes_count counter,
view_count counter,
comments_count counter,
post_id uuid,
PRIMARY KEY (post_id)
);
```

My Question is now:

If I want to show a post with likes. How I query it ? I cant join the post_counts table so how I do it ? It should be in the posts_by_user query or I am wrong ?

```
Output as User Interface:

--username
--profilimage
--likes
--follow-user
```

Comment: Can you clarify if the user interface will include post or not? Post is not part of it, but you mention that you want to show a post with likes.
How do you decide, which post to show? Let's say it is 1 million posts, what is the select criteria for posts to be shown?

Comment: You may have to separate the requests

Comment: In NOSQL dbs you cannot think like Relacional dbs. So for each query, you create a table with all you need. If you want to do a join, you can use a spark to do it for you. However the performing is not satisfying. So for modeling you schema you need look what data you want, create a table and then create a mechanism to load it.